# Is there a convenient way to generate a sorted array from the values of a HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<CustomClass, Double>` that I'm populating inside a loop, and I'd like to produce a `CustomClass[]` which is sorted by the corresponding doubles in my HashMap.

I can do this by initializing an empty array of doubles outside my loop and populating it with the same doubles that I used as values in my HashMap.  After looping, I can use something like `Arrays.sort(my_doubles_array)` to sort my doubles, then iterate through them, comparing HashMap values and picking out matching keys.  This way works, but it seems like there's unnecessary work here.

Is there a way I can do this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using streams:

```
CustomClass[] array =
    map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(comparingDouble(Entry::getValue))
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .toArray(CustomClass[]::new);
```

An alternative without streams:

```
CustomClass[] array = map.keySet().toArray(new CustomClass[0]);
Arrays.sort(array, comparingDouble(map::get));
```

And you can do it in pre-Java 8 by replacing the comparator with an anonymous comparator (or similar):

```
new Comparator<CustomClass>() {
  public int compare(CustomClass a, CustomClass b) {
    return Double.compare(map.get(a), map.get(b));
  }
}
```

Comment: of course,... `Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)`